# Error in compiling in jgrasp

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayMethSumPer
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int x,sum,copysum;
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("enter how many integers you want to enter");
       x = keyboard.nextInt();
       int[] plan=new int [x];
       System.out.println("You said you wanted to enter "+x+" integers, you may now proceed with entering them.");


       for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
           plan[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
           sum=plan[i]+plan[i];
           float[] percentage=(plan[i]*100/sum);
           if(i==x-1)
               System.out.println("your first integer is "+percentage[0]+" percent of the sum");
       }
   }
}
```

I am trying to compile this but at the line :

```
float[] percentage=(plan[i]*100/sum);
```

It shows the error

> arrayMethSumPer.java:18: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to float[].

I understand what this means but is division incompatible between these types?

Can someone help me get it to properly print out the percent for each value is of the sum?

Another thing I could've done is to cast it by using (float)() or (int)()

Comment: Why, exactly, are you trying to get an array out of a single multiplication and division of a scalar? The error says you can't convert to `float[]`, not `float`. Note the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely divider `int`s and `floats` however, you cannot divide a  *single* number by an *array* of numbers.  The `[]` you see in the error message is the key.  You are doing integer division, however you say the variable expected is a `float[]`

If you meant to put this value at a s*pecific index* in the array you can do it like this:

```
percentage[i] = (plan[i] * 100) / sum;
```

However, it doesn't look like you have a previously created array to it into.  If you're looking to just declare a new variable you do it **WITHOUT** the brackets so it's just regular `float` variable as such:

```
float = plan[i] * 100 / sum;
```

This will compile.  If you do in fact want to store them in an array make sure you declare the array **BEFORE** your loop as such:

```
int[] list = new int[x];
double[] percentages = new double[x];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `float[] percentage=(plan[i]*100/sum);` statement you are trying to assign an int value to a float array. This can't be done.
Either you have to assign the value of `plan[i]*100/sum`to an `int` or `float` base on your requirement.
e.g.

```
int x = plan[i]*100/sum; // int/int -> int
```

But I think you want here to get the value with decimals so it should be

```
percentage[/*desired index*/] = (float) (plan[i] * 100) / sum;
```

Other than those things, in your for loop you are creating the array in each iteration. That is really bad. I think you should have something like

```
float[] percentage= new float[x];
for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    plan[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    sum = plan[i]+plan[i];
    percentage[x] = (float)(plan[i]*100/sum);
    if(i == x-1)
         System.out.println("your first integer is "+percentage[0]+" percent of the sum");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how to print the percent each value is of the sum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PercentCalc{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to enter? :\n");
    int x = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[] list = new int[x];
    double [] percentValue = new double[x];

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i =0; i<list.length; i++){
      int num = i+1;
      System.out.print("Please enter #" + num + ": ");
      list[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
      sum = list[i] + sum;
    }

    for(int i =0; i<list.length; i++){
      percentValue[i] = ((double)list[i] / sum)*100.0;
      System.out.printf("%d is %1.2f percent of the sum.\n", list[i], percentValue[i]);
    }
  }
}
```